# How to delete a node in two clone node in neo4j using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

run this Cypher query twice to create clone of the Actor

```
CREATE (n:Actor { name:"Tom Hanks" });
```

Now i have this two nodes, when i ran this query

```
MATCH (actor:Actor) RETURN actor;
```

I got the resultset as

**actor**

(1:Actor {name:"Tom Hanks"})

(2:Actor {name:"Tom Hanks"})

Now how to delete only the 2nd node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
MATCH (actor:Actor {name: 'Tom Hanks'})
WITH actor
SKIP 1
DELETE actor;
```

Comment: i struck upon another method too

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the nodes, loop through the tail of the collection in a for-each loop, and delete each. It works for your case with two "Tom Hanks" nodes, but equally well if you have five or fifty, deleting every except one.

```
MATCH (a:Actor { name:"Tom Hanks" })
WITH collect (a) as aa
FOREACH (b IN TAIL (aa)) |
    DELETE b)
```

or with list slicing

```
MATCH (a:Actor { name:"Tom Hanks" })
WITH collect (a) as aa
FOREACH (b IN aa[1..] |
    DELETE b)
```

Comment: Yes, apparently the collect has to happen beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the identifier of the node, then you can use that to delete the node.

```
MATCH (actor:Actor { name: "Tom Hanks" })
WHERE id(actor)=1
DELETE actor;
```

Comment: You should probably not rely on the id of the actor as a general means to delete the second one.

Comment: yeah! but in my application the first node is a part of a big chain and so didn't want to risk that node to get deleted